# R manipulation of dataset from .txt

Tags: r, database, list

I'm importing a .txt in R with

```
my_data<-read.delim("data",as.is=1)
```

I got a data frame with 3000 list.

lines look like this

```
Hello world !
C ID equipement
A 
3 5 6 45
123 567 762 
876 7889 986
B  
bye world
```

Here what i want to do with this imported file.

1/ Select only lines between the line who begin with "A" and the line who begin with "B". Those lines position can change if I download another .txt

2/ Select ID equipement from the list who begin with "C" and add the value to all the list between A and B, with the separator " "

To get list between A and B i did this:

```
id1 <- (which(my_data=="A")+1)
id2<- (which(my_data=="B")-1)
d<- my_data[id1:id2,1]
ll <- strsplit(d," ")
```

ll is a vector of list, and for example `ll[1]= "3 5 6 45"`

Now i want to add ID equipment to all those lists.

Any idea how to do this?
Also, if anyone has better idea for my lines selection between A and B I would be happy to see it!

thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For extracting the lines between A and B you can simply use `startsWith`, e.g.

```
# Your data
# This is the structure obtained using "readLines"
my_data <- c("Hello world !", "C ID equipement", "A ", "3 5 6 45", "123 567 762 ", 
             "876 7889 986", "B  ", "bye world")


strsplit(my_data[(which(startsWith(my_data, "A")) + 1L):(which(startsWith(my_data, "B")) - 1L)], " ")
# [[1]]
# [1] "3"  "5"  "6"  "45"
# 
# [[2]]
# [1] "123" "567" "762"
# 
# [[3]]
# [1] "876"  "7889" "986"
```

And to retrieve the ID you can use regex, e.g.

```
pat <- "^C\\s+(.*?)\\s+.*"   # Expression starts with a "C", then space, then something, then space, then something
gsub(pat, "\\1", grep(pat, my_data, value = TRUE))
# [1] "ID"
```

Finally, for adding the ID, a very simple approach is to use `lapply`, e.g.

```
lapply(l, function(x, ID) as.numeric(x) + ID, ID = 1L)
# [[1]]
# [1]  4  6  7 46
# 
# [[2]]
# [1] 124 568 763
# 
# [[3]]
# [1]  877 7890  987
```

where `l` denotes the above list and `ID` is set to `1` for demonstration purposes (since in the example there is no actual ID).